# I Can't attack Onclick on item with dynamic class

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I' using kind of two times validation to ensure the user really wants to delete the item.

```
<span class="addvalidationmsg" data-actionresult="DeleteInstallation">CLICK ME</span>
```

First when user click on item, I replace classes and change message, and no POST, just changes on DOM:

```
$(".addvalidationmsg").click(function () {
                // remove validation message
                $(this).removeClass("addvalidationmsg");
                // add ajaxcall
                $(this).addClass("ajaxcall");
                // add text
                $(this).text("are you sure? Click again");

                return false;
            });
```

Then, when I click the second time, thanks to the new class, it launchs this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ajaxcall", function () {
                alert("POST");
            });
    });
```

Problem is that I just want to launch POST only on the second click. If I return false on the first function, nothing happend after that and if I remove it, it launches the POST twice (once every click)

If I remove the return false; on the first function, then the second function is called when user press the item the first time (why again)?

How to make this work?

A little [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2xaa26yr/1/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say it's not happening, yet your fiddle seems to be working perfectly as you describe...?

Comment: Fiddle is working alright,

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It's due to the removal of `return false`. That's stopping the propagation to the delegated event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are statically binding a click event to an element that you found using a class selector. It does not matter if the class is removed later as the handler is already bound to the element.

Change to a delegated event handler. This is then bound to an ancestor element instead:

```
$(document).on('click', ".addvalidationmsg", function () {
```

As the jQuery selector is only run at *event time*, not *event registration time*, it will no longer match when the class is removed *and the event will not fire again*.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2xaa26yr/2/

Note: I had to put in a console.log as the repeated click was not "visible" :)

The second problem "was" the `return false` stopping event propagation, but that goes away too with the above code.

If you never intend re-enabling the button, another option is to use `one` instead. This will only fire the event once.... ever:

```
$(".addvalidationmsg").one('click', function () {
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2xaa26yr/3/

Comment: okay, it solve my problem, but why do I have to put the $(document).on('click', ".addvalidationmsg"... ? This selector can run at launch time, isn't it?

Comment: @clement: Yes, but if you go with my first option *it will stop firing when the class no longer exists on it*. Your original had two conflicting problem (return false was stopping repeats being visible, but the first handler *was* still firing every click). Personally I would use `one` as described in the second option.

Comment: @clement: Added more explanation of the problem for you.

Answer (score -2):

you can try using $(document).on() also for the first event.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("click", '.addvalidationmsg', function() {
        // remove validation message
        $(this).removeClass("addvalidationmsg");
        // add ajaxcall
        $(this).addClass("ajaxcall");
        // add text
        $(this).text("are you sure? Click again");
       return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".ajaxcall", function () {
        alert("POST");
    });
});
```

Comment: Please check for identical answers before posting :)